# Написать SQL-запрос, который вернет выборку со всеми полями за предыдущую дату

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задание такое:

> Необходимо написать SQL-запрос, который вернет выборку со всеми полями
> за предыдущую дату.

Вот таблица:

[image]

и она в [google sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10iuUzTNgIkfsaebEpRRo49xn_J-nBzGvflQektUa-dI/edit?usp=sharing)

В итоге:

- Запрос должен вывести все столбцы и строки за предыдущую дату (в
  данном примере 3.06.2022).
- Запрос не должен содержать фиксированное значение даты, то есть в нем
  должна быть логика определения предыдущей даты в зависимости от
  текущей.

Пробовала через LAG и ранжирование строк, но не получается.
Не прошу полного решения, хотелось бы самой сделать.

Но возможно есть уже готовые алгоритмы или операторы, которые решают эту задачу, а я о них не знаю (не нашла). Или направьте в правильное русло рассуждений.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-sql)

Comment: *все столбцы и строки за предыдущую дату (в данном примере 3.06.2022)* А почему в "данном примере" предыдущая дата - именно 3.06.2022? PS. [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: "А почему в "данном примере" предыдущая дата - именно 3.06.2022?" 
Так сказано в задании, я сама толком не понимаю почему, долго думала, решила, что это означает , что есть последняя дата (10.06) и нужно именно предыдущую к ней. Но эта фраза из задания..
Попробую вставить таблицу.

Comment: Находите максимальную дату (М1). Находите максимальную дату среди всех дат, меньших М1 (М2). Выводите все строки, у которых дата равна М2.